# With jQuery always wait for items to fully load before counting them

Tags: jquery, onload

I am trying to have a "Load More" button for some Wordpress content, if there are more than 9 posts I want to show a "Load More" button. My code works but it is incinsistent sometimes and I'm not sure why, how can I make sure it always waits for everything to load before starting to count items?

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var propertiesLength = $('.card.property').length;
    var clientsLength = $('.card.client').length;

    if(propertiesLength > 9){
      $('#loadMore').css('display', 'inline-block');
    } else if(clientsLength > 8){
      $('#loadMore').css('display', 'inline-block');
    }
  });
```

Comment: How are you getting the content of Wordpress? Is it an `ajax` call or is it a call to an `api`?

Comment: if your `.card` s are loaded dynamically, you might have to bind the display of the count to the loading of the cards (instead of the loading of the window)

Comment: wrap it in a $(document).ready(function () {})